# How do you parse text that appears before the dictionary key-values?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure how to best describe it, but if I have a dictionary that has text or a name before the actual key-values, how would I pull that out of the dictionary to get to the actual key-value pairs?

```
{'students':[
{'username': 'Mike1@example.com', 'enabledUser': true, 'password': null, 'identifier': '996_STU_10100001', 'dateLastModified': '2018-08-01T17:13:40.003Z', 'middleName': 'Sierra', 'userIds': null, 'familyName': 'Aadgoo', 'sms': null, 'phone': '8888880001', 'grades': ['01'], 'sourcedId': 'STU_10100001', 'role': 'student', 'status': 'active', 'orgs': [{'href': '~/ims/oneroster/v1p1/orgs/996', 'type': 'org', 'sourcedId': '996'}], 'agents': [], 'givenName': 'Mike', 'email': 'Mike1@example.com', 'metadata': null}
{'username': 'Jonathan2@example.com', 'enabledUser': true, 'password': null, 'identifier': '996_STU_10100002', 'dateLastModified': '2018-08-01T17:13:40.003Z', 'middleName': 'Alpha', 'userIds': null, 'familyName': 'Bravo', 'sms': null, 'phone': '8888880002', 'grades': ['05'], 'sourcedId': 'STU_10100002', 'role': 'student', 'status': 'active', 'orgs': [{'href': '~/ims/oneroster/v1p1/orgs/996', 'type': 'org', 'sourcedId': '996'}], 'agents': [], 'givenName': 'Jonathan', 'email': 'Johnathan2@example.com', 'metadata': null}...]}
```

Desired keyvalues to pull from:

```
'username': 'Mike1@example.com', 'enabledUser': true, 'password': null, 'identifier': '996_STU_10100001', 'dateLastModified': '2018-08-01T17:13:40.003Z', 'middleName': 'Sierra', 'userIds': null, 'familyName': 'Aadgoo', 'sms': null, 'phone': '8888880001', 'grades': ['01'], 'sourcedId': 'STU_10100001', 'role': 'student', 'status': 'active', 'orgs': [{'href': '~/ims/oneroster/v1p1/orgs/996', 'type': 'org', 'sourcedId': '996'}], 'agents': [], 'givenName': 'Mike', 'email': 'Mike1@example.com', 'metadata': null
'username': 'Jonathan2@example.com', 'enabledUser': true, 'password': null, 'identifier': '996_STU_10100002', 'dateLastModified': '2018-08-01T17:13:40.003Z', 'middleName': 'Alpha', 'userIds': null, 'familyName': 'Bravo', 'sms': null, 'phone': '8888880002', 'grades': ['05'], 'sourcedId': 'STU_10100002', 'role': 'student', 'status': 'active', 'orgs': [{'href': '~/ims/oneroster/v1p1/orgs/996', 'type': 'org', 'sourcedId': '996'}], 'agents': [], 'givenName': 'Jonathan', 'email': 'Johnathan2@example.com', 'metadata': null
```

Comment: what are your actual keyvalues?

Comment: see the second code snippet for the desired key values

Comment: whats wrong with `your_dict['students']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean nested dicts. So the value of the outer Dict is a Dict. In your case it is a Dict of list of dicts

> your_dict['students'][0]['username']

To get the key values you can use

> your_dict.keys()

or in a loop

```
for key in your_dict:
   for list_item in your_dict[key]:
      for key2 in list_item:
         print(key2, list_item[key2])
```

Comment: thanks Nauer. Is there an easy way to have the for loop iterate each key sequentially through the entire keys? If not, I can figure it out later.

Comment: Nested loops for nested dicts/lists

Answer (score 1):

You can put this on a variable and run:

```
for dic in variable['students']:
  do_something_with_dic(dic) # dic -> your key-value pairs
```

You might have to correct somethings if that's the dictionary on your code, like `true` -> `True`.